# How to register routes from .yaml and via annotations with Symfony Routing Component in PHP app

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have simple php app and want to use symfony routing component to create routes both via annotations and yaml

I can create routes in yaml. Commented part work when definying routes in yaml

```
    foos_route:
    path:     /foos
    defaults: { _controller: 'App\Controller\MainController', _method: 'index3'}

#   foo_placeholder_route:
#   path:     /foo/{id}
#   defaults: { _controller: 'App\Controller\MainController', _method: 'index2'}
#   requirements:
#      id: '[0-9]+'
```

Controller part with annotations and 1 method for yaml

```
class MainController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/foo", name="foo_route")
     */
    public static function index()
    {
        echo 'aaaaa';
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/foo/{id}", name="foo_route2")
     */
    public static function index2()
    {
        echo 'bbbbb';
    }

    public static function index3()
    {
        echo 'cccccc';
    }
}
```

Index.php part

```
try
{
    $fileLocator = new FileLocator([__DIR__. '/config/']);

    // Init RequestContext object
    $requestContext = new RequestContext();
    $requestContext->fromRequest(Request::createFromGlobals());

    /*WORKING YAML PART*/
    $router = new Router(
        new YamlFileLoader($fileLocator),
        'routes.yaml',
        [],
        $requestContext
    );

    // Find the current route
    $parameters = $router->match($requestContext->getPathInfo());
    $controller = new $parameters['_controller'];
    echo $controller->{$parameters['_method']}();
    /*WORKING YAML PART*/

    /*WORK ANNOTATION PART*/
    $loader = new AnnotationDirectoryLoader(
        $fileLocator,
        new AnnotatedRouteControllerLoader(
            new AnnotationReader()
        )
    );

    $routes = $loader->load(__DIR__.'/app/Controller/');

    // Init UrlMatcher object
    $matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $requestContext);

    // Find the current route
    $parameters = $matcher->match($requestContext->getPathInfo());
    call_user_func($parameters['_controller']);
    /*WORKING ANNOTATIONS PART*/
}
catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I followed [Routing Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html) documentation it's working, but I can't understand concat those 2 parts that I could define rotes from both way annotations and from .yaml

SOLUTION:
I'm not sure if this is the best desicion but I used loaderResolver

```
$fileLocator = new FileLocator([__DIR__. '/config/']);

$yamlLoader = new YamlFileLoader($fileLocator);
$annotationsLoader = new AnnotationDirectoryLoader(
    $fileLocator,
    new AnnotatedRouteControllerLoader(
        new AnnotationReader()
    )
);

$loaderResolver = new LoaderResolver([$yamlLoader, $annotationsLoader]);
$delegatingLoader = new DelegatingLoader($loaderResolver);

$routes = new RouteCollection();
$routes->addCollection($delegatingLoader->load(__DIR__ . '/config/routes.yaml'));

$matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $requestContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

`UrlMatcher` (used in both cases) throws exceptions when no route is found.
Then you just have to catch them exceptions, and then go to the following method if the 1st one is not working:

```php
try
{
    /*WORKING YAML PART*/
    //...
    /*WORKING YAML PART*/
} catch (ResourceNotFoundException | NoConfigurationException $e)
    try {
        /*WORKING ANNOTATION PART*/
        //...
        /*WORKING ANNOTATIONS PART*/
    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

https://github.com/symfony/routing/blob/master/Matcher/UrlMatcherInterface.php#L36

Should be working.

Comment: thx for a help, but I did it differently, added solution to my post